# Does the following always hold for every vector space base?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If we have a vector space basis $B_1 = 
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} \right\}$

If we take the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3&2\\1 &1 &1\\1 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$
We transpose it and then row reduce it Then we would get:
$$$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0&0\\0 &0 &1\\0 &1 &0\end{bmatrix}$$$$

Now if we take the rows as vectors for basis, we get a new basis for basis $B_1$.

Does this procedure always work for every basis ?
Is there a formal name of this procedure ?

Comment: The second matrix is not in reduced row echelon form, it should be the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the fact that row operations preserve linear independence of the rows. This is obvious except perhaps for the operation $R_i \leftarrow R_i + kR_j \quad (i \neq j)$, so here's the proof:

Assume some linear combination $$\sum_{k \neq i} \alpha^k R_k + \alpha^i (R_i + kR_j) = 0;$$

regrouping terms on the left-hand side yields $$\sum_{k \neq i,j} \alpha^k R_k + \alpha^i R_i + (\alpha^i k + \alpha^j)R_j = 0,$$ so linear independence of the family $\{R_i\}$ yields $\alpha^k = 0 \quad \forall k \neq j$ and $\alpha^ik + \alpha^j = \alpha ^j =0$, proving that the new set of rows is also independent.

Answer (score 2):

The columns of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$ if and only if $A$ is invertible, which holds if and only if the reduced row echelon form of $A$ is the identity matrix, which holds if and only if the reduced row echelon form of $A^T$ is the identity matrix, which holds if and only if the rows of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Comment: I understand. Actually my question was, if we only know the non reduced basis, and we take the vectors from basis and create the matrix out of them, then can we always do the procedure in the question ?

Comment: Yes, and you will always get the standard basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$.

Comment: So if the question would be, find some basis for some "random vector space", we can do that procedure and show it in standard basis of some field to the n. Right?

Comment: If the columns of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$, the rows of $\operatorname{RREF}(A)$ will be the standard basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$.